# Delaying code or Tomcat hook for Listener

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using Apache CXF for developing Webservices and using Tomcat

Inside my Webservice , i am calling another web service as shown

```
String host = "http://localhost:8080/bayer-ws-1.0/bayer/soap";
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
factory.setServiceClass(BayerService.class);
factory.setAddress(host);
BayerService client = (BayerService)factory.create();
client.distracts(request);
```

There was a error after adding these lines .

I found out that

Tomcat starts up all the wars prior to actually starting up a listener on the 
port.   Thus, you cannot call off to a port 8080 thing until AFTER everything 
is completely up and running.   I think tomcat has some listeners or something 
you can hook into, but I'm not really sure.   A simple timer or something to 
delay the above code for a couple seconds, if possible, should also work.

Now my question is 
Please let me know  how can i delay this piece of  code??
Don't know if this is the proper solution or not ??

I have mentioned load-on-start-up  for this war to 15550 , but no effect
Please share