# How to make Tomcat start Listener First

Tags: tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delaying code or Tomcat hook for Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252628/delaying-code-or-tomcat-hook-for-listener)

Inside my Webservice , i am calling another webservice as

```
http://localhost:8080/bayer-ws-1.0/bayer/soap
```

But i noticed , Tomcat starts up all the wars prior to actually starting up a listener on the port.

Thus, we cannot call off to a port 8080 thing until AFTER everything is completely up and running.

How can we solve this problem ,  to make tomcat to start Listeners first
I think tomcat has some listeners or something you can hook into, but I'm not really sure.

I am using Tomcat 6 , please help me .

In case the question is confusing , this is what i want to obtain

Tomcat starts up all the wars prior to actually starting up a listener on the port. Thus, you cannot call off to a port 8080 thing until AFTER everything is completely up and running. I think tomcat has some listeners or something you can hook into, but I'm not really sure. A simple timer or something to delay the above code for a couple seconds, if possible, should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't completely understand your question. But you can delete the extra folders/war in your $tomcat_home/webapps directory to lower the start time.

Apart from that when Tomcat starts it will initialize your application .i.e. load it, run the listeners etc. about which you can't do much.

You can also use Jetty if this is for development. Jetty is lighter and faster. Apart from that you can avoid restarting your server for every change by using something like JRebel.